# GraphView not sizing properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-graphview

I'm using [Graph View](http://www.android-graphview.org/) to plot my **bar graphs** in the app I'm developing and everything is working fine in portrait mode. However,when changed to landscape, the graphs's labels get out of line with  the data points as shown in the pictures below:

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

As you can see, the labels are miss aligned with respect to the bars, Here is my code for this:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chart, container, false)
    val graph = view?.findViewById(R.id.graph) as GraphView

    val staticLabelsFormatter = StaticLabelsFormatter(graph)
    staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(arrayOf("Basics", "Loops", "Functions"))
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter)
    graph.gridLabelRenderer.verticalLabelsColor = Color.WHITE
    graph.gridLabelRenderer.horizontalLabelsColor = Color.WHITE
    graph.gridLabelRenderer.gridStyle = GridLabelRenderer.GridStyle.NONE
    graph.gridLabelRenderer.isVerticalLabelsVisible = false

    graph.viewport.setMinX(0.0)
    graph.viewport.setMinY(0.0)
    graph.viewport.setMaxX(2.0)
    graph.viewport.setMaxY(6.0)
    graph.viewport.isXAxisBoundsManual = true
    graph.viewport.isYAxisBoundsManual = true

    val basics = arguments!!.getDouble("basics")
    val loops = arguments!!.getDouble("loops")
    val functions  = arguments!!.getDouble("functions")

    val series = BarGraphSeries(arrayOf(
            DataPoint(0.37, basics)
    ))
    val series2 = BarGraphSeries(arrayOf(
            DataPoint(1.0, loops)
    ))
    val series3 = BarGraphSeries(arrayOf(
            DataPoint(1.6, functions)
    ))

    series.setColor(Color.GREEN)
    series2.setColor(Color.CYAN)
    series3.setColor(Color.MAGENTA)

    series.setAnimated(true)
    series2.setAnimated(true)
    series3.setAnimated(true)

    series.setDrawValuesOnTop(true)
    series2.setDrawValuesOnTop(true)
    series3.setDrawValuesOnTop(true)

    series.setValuesOnTopColor(Color.WHITE)
    series2.setValuesOnTopColor(Color.WHITE)
    series3.setValuesOnTopColor(Color.WHITE)

    graph.addSeries(series)
    graph.addSeries(series2)
    graph.addSeries(series3)

    return view
}
```

Is there a way to assign y values to labels instead of a x data point ? This issue is happening now  because I'm forced to fix a y value to a x value. Idly, it would be to the label. Or is there a way to fix labels to a certain x value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Try To use This code

   private LineChart mChart;

   mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
   mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
   mChart.setPinchZoom(true);

   LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(x, "");
   set1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 82, 159));
   set1.setLineWidth(1.5f);
   set1.setCircleRadius(4f);
   LineData data1 = new LineData(y, set1);
   mChart.setData(data1);
   mChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Is it possible to get it done with GraphView instead ? Because, the animations there are quite nice

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: `LineChart` and `LineDataSet` is part of graph view ?

Comment: yes u don't know that linechart and graphView is same

Comment: implementation 'com.github.AnyChart:AnyChart-Android:0.2.9'
 library